# Can a number be used to name a MySQL table column?

Tags: mysql, ddl

I have a table that has column names like 25, 50, 100, etc..

When trying to update the table I get an error, no matter how I do it

```
UPDATE table SET '25'='100' WHERE id = '1'
```

I have tried quoting and backticking every which way but without success.

The error is always along the lines of:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''25'=100 WHERE id=1' at line 1

If I change the column name to `twentyfive` - I don't have a problem, but that's not what I want. Is it possible to use a number as a column name?

Comment: I've provided an answer, but I'd still like to say that I think using numeric field names is a bit unorthodox, and I'd tend to just prefix the fields.

Comment: refer to this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711470/laravel-how-to-access-column-with-number-name-of-a-table

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html):

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

Which means you must quote it with back ticks like `25`:

```
UPDATE table SET `25`='100' WHERE id='1'
```

Comment: Thanks. After reading some I agree, prefixing the column is a better practice.

Answer (score 6):

As others have said, you can back-tick the *names* of tables, columns, etc.  Just make sure you're not back-ticking your *values* otherwise it'll interpret them as column names.  So in your example only the 25 needs to be back ticked:

```
UPDATE table SET `25`=100 WHERE id=1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need it to be based on a number for some reason, you can append some simple prefix to the number in all cases (e.g. "col25", "col87", etc).

Comment: A number is fine as long as you quote things properly.

Answer (score 2):

Check here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist
>   solely of digits.

So yes, you can do it -- you need to use backtics around the name.

Answer (score -1):

Names in MySQL can *start* with a digit, but cannot be *entirely* digits — they cannot be confusable with an integer.  So, no.

And if you start your identifier with a digit, you should be pretty sure you're sticking with MySQL because many (most?) other database engines require an alpha character at the front of column names.

(As stated in the comments, a fully integer column name *is* allowed if you consistently use the backtick character — if you tried backticks and still got a syntax error, post the precise backtick syntax you used).

Also, of course, you're going to produce some difficult to read SQL if you opt for integer-named columns!

Comment: Are you sure about that? I just created a table called `1` with a column named `2`, I had to liberally apply backticks of course.

Comment: This is not true in MySQL. ;)

Comment: Indeed, you are both correct (MySQL documentation better than at informit.com).