# getting error on inserting

Tags: php, variables, insert

Do you see any problem? I get this error.

```
$col = 360;
$col1 = 350;

$esim = 0;
$esim1 = 1;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_table ($col, $col1) VALUES('$esim', '$esim1')") or die(mysql_error());
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '360, 350) VALUES('0', '1')' at line 1

Comment: where is table name? is table is table name?

Comment: can we have table name and column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are suffering from the same problem as here:
[Can a number be used to name a MySQL table column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975417/can-a-number-used-to-name-a-sql-column)

Put your table and column names into backticks.

Answer (score 1):

Change 'table' to `table`. The word 'table' is reserved. More info about reserved words: https://drupal.org/node/141051

`Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.`(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
  $col = "`360`";
  $col1 = "`350`";

  $esim = 0;
  $esim1 = 1;

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_table ($col, $col1) VALUES('$esim', '$esim1')") or die(mysql_error());
```

**If column name is in number it should be enclosed with ``**

Answer (score 1):

It is tested it is working :)
you have problem in your column name. it is treated as an integer value not as a column name.

```
$col = 360;
$col1 = 350;
```

Can you use backticks in name like :

```
$col = "`360`";
$col1 = "`350`";
```