# Calculating a Table with PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to build a table for my NCAA bracket and I am having issues getting the calculations to work. Essentially, I'm trying to achieve the following process:

1. Does Gary's choice (Column 4) equal the Result (Column 2)?
2. If so, add the points for that game (Column 3) to variable $total.
3. Repeat for each row (representing game), so at the end $total equals total points.

   ```
   +-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
   | Game  | Result | Points | 101   | 102   |
   +-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
   | game1 | Team1  |      2 | Team1 | Team2 |
   +-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
   | game2 | Team2  |      2 | Team1 | Team2 |
   +-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
   | game3 | Team1  |      6 | Team2 | Team1 |
   +-------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
   ```

---

**What I've tried so far**

```
for ($i=101; $i<=102; $i++) {

    $stmt = $conn->query('SELECT game, points, result, '.$i.' FROM data');

    echo 'SELECT game, points, '.$i.', result FROM data';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt))
        {
            $result = $row['result'];
            $points = $row['points'];
            $choice = $row[''.$i.''];

                if ($result == $choice) {
                    $total = $total.$points;
                }
        }

        echo $total;      

}
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Thanks Dave Chen for helping me with the table. @raygo, this is what I've been tweaking so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you can't simply name the columns of your table numbers without identifiers (`) as was clearly pointed out in this SO article: **[Can a number be used to name a MySQL table column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975417/can-a-number-used-to-name-a-sql-column)**

Thanks all.