# Cannot insert column containing colon in column name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert a column with column name 00:18:e7:f9:65:a6 with the statement

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tblwifi_information ADD "00:18:e7:f9:65:a6" INT
```

...but it throws an error:

```
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"00:18:e7:f9:65:a6" INT' at line 1 */
```

in Heidi SQL. I am using MySQL database.

When I try to add the column manually b going to the structure of the table it works and does not give any error but when I run this statement it does not allow me. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try it using backticks? i.e. `\`` instead of `"` around the identifier?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a number used to name a sql column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975417/can-a-number-used-to-name-a-sql-column)

Comment: why in all that is holy are you creating columns with mac/ipv6? addresses

Comment: How do you do it manually?

Comment: He means that this column name, for a lack of a better word, is stupid.

Comment: Its not only numbers but a mixture in my case I guess

Comment: can you add the php command you use for this, maybe there is an error there. I also think the problem is the mixtute of different symbols, so you should try yo create this field in your database as a Char.

Comment: So, you are going to write `SELECT 00:18:e7:f9:65:a6 FROM tblwifi_information`?

Comment: You need to go away, relook at how your structuring your database and please to save our sanity read up on normalised database structures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran your query:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tblwifi_information ADD "00:18:e7:f9:65:a6" INT
```

and got the same error. I then ran:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tblwifi_information ADD `00:18:e7:f9:65:a6` INT
```

and it worked. Pretty sure you need to change " to `

Fail with double qoutes:
[image: Failed with double quotes]

Success with backticks:
[image: Success with backticks]

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure but I suspect that it could have something to do with your php, and not the query itself. If you haven't done so already, I would try executing another very basic query with php, like `SELECT * FROM ...` just to confirm your db connection is working ok.

Answer (score 2):

use backticks for columnname

change

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tblwifi_information ADD "00:18:e7:f9:65:a6" INT
```

TO

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tblwifi_information ADD `00:18:e7:f9:65:a6` INT
```

## [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d248b/1)

Answer (score 1):

To add something to the story, when querying multiple tables, you have to use following expression:

```
`tablename`.`columnname`
```

(NOT `tablename.columnname` )

I took me some time to figure it out, so I hope it helps someone :)

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_product p
JOIN tb_brand b ON (  `p`.`tb_brand:IDbrand` =  `b`.`IDbrand` ) 
WHERE IDfamily = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont really know what you are trying to achive here pal.
instead of:

```
00:18:e7:f9:65:a6
```

to

```
00_18_e7_f9_65_a6
```

then adjust your code to replace ":" to "_" in php or mysql.

**in sql:**

```
Replace(table_name, ':', '_');
```

**in PHP:**

```
srt_replace(':','_',$query);
```