# Can numbers be a part of column names in MySQL? if yes, is it advisable?

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if I can use numbers in conjuction of letters in column names. If yes, I would like to know if it is advisable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a number used to name a sql column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975417/can-a-number-used-to-name-a-sql-column)

Comment: @Ben I modified my question

Comment: Can you add an example of a "normally numbers"?  Maybe add the create statement you're looking to use.

Comment: @Ray I modified the text of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, it does not violate anything (at least mysql 5.5 and higher).

Refer to this for full spec of naming for schema elements: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html

However, I would not recommending using all numbers entirely like "123", "245" as doing this:

- it's not descriptive or indicative of anything anyone other than you would be able to discern
- need to escape use in queries with backtics.

Using numbers in column names in conjunction with letters is perfectly fine (such as "order_1", "order_2", ect...), no backticks to access needed.

Comment: must I use backticks even if the numbers are in the middle of the name? For example `name_1_surname` or like this `name_1`

Comment: Backticks needs to be used when the name of the object (database, table, column, index, trigger etc) can be interpreted as something else in the context. For example, if it is a MySQL reserved word or a function name then, most of the times, it needs to be enclosed in backticks. Also, if the name contains only of digits then it always needs to be enclosed in backticks or MySQL will interpret it as a number instead.