# Django - name a Model field with a number

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I would like to name the fields of my Django model with integers. 
I found the way to do it in [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975437/4146521) but the same seems not applicable in Django. If I write something like:

```
class WidgetContributionDevelopment(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, db_column='site_id', default=None)
    `1` = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    `2` = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    `3` = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

I get a syntax error.
Is there a way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Name django fields with numbers is a pretty bas idea to my mind ^^

Comment: ok, this may make sense :) it was just: I have numbers from 1 to 7 coming from an `isoweekday()` function and I was wondering if there was any shortcut instead of mapping these numbers to the column name, and make the query then.